# Access Ansible inventory variables using with_items and vmware_guest for vSphere

Tags: ansible, vmware, ansible-inventory

I'm trying to convert a playbook which deploys vSphere VMs.  The current version
of the playbook gets individual IP addresses and source template information
from `vars/main.yml` in the role (I'm using the [best practice](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout) directory layout.)

```yaml
vms:
  - name: demo-server-0
    ip_address: 1.1.1.1
  - name: demo-server-1
    ip_address: 1.1.1.2
```

Template, and other information is stored elsewhere in the `vars.yml` file but
it makes more sense to use the standard inventory, so I created these entries
in the inventory file:

```yaml
    test_and_demo:
      hosts:
        demo-server-0:
          ip-address: 1.1.1.1
        demo-server-1:
          ip-address: 1.1.1.2
      vars:
        vc_template: xdr-template-1
```

The play is pretty much unchanged, apart from this key change:

FROM:

```yaml
  with_items: '{{ vms }}'
```

TO:

```yaml
  with_items: "{{ query('inventory_hostnames', 'test_and_demo') }}"
```

But this throws the following error:

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyVim'
failed: [localhost] (item=demo-deployer) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "demo-deployer", "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (PyVmomi) on lubuntu's Python /usr/bin/python3. Please read the module documentation and install it in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"}
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyVim'
```

I don't believe this is a platform issue, as reverting back to `with_items: '{{ vms }}'`
works just fine (`vars\main.yml` still exists and duplicates data).

I'm probably using query incorrectly but can anyone give me a hint what I'm
doing wrong?

### Accessing sub-values

If I can get the VMs to deploy using `with_items:` + `query` I'd then need to
access the variables of the host and group for the various items I need to
specify, can someone advise me here, too.

Many thanks.

Comment: The problem is elsewhere in your task/role/playbook you are not showing. Chances to get help with so partial info are close to 0. You will need to create an [MCVE](/help/mcve). Side note: 1) looping at task level (i.e. with `loop:` or `with_*:`) on list of targets in your inventory is in most cases a bad practice. You usually want to rely on the natural `hosts:` loop at play level. 2) if you want to ignore point 1, you don't need to query to loop on a group: `{{ groups['test_and_demo'] }}` will give your the names and e.g. `{{ hostvars['demo-server-0'].ip-address }}` the relevant var for host.

Comment: @Zeitounator Thanks for the comment, your notes are interesting.  As `vmware_guest` demands to run as `-hosts: localhost`, looping) through hosts is not available to me at the Play level as far as I understand.

Comment: Wrong: you can loop on all host at play level and `delegate_to: localhost` in needed tasks. You will still access the vars from the looped host on those tasks. You will need to `gather_facts: false` to make sure ansible does not try to connect to your not-yet-existing host.

Answer (score 0):

Although I was convinced the problem was in the way I was doing the query, it was in the root Play which I hadn't noticed.  By adding `become: yes` I think it was switching to the root user which didn't have the module installed.

Once it was removed, the problem was resolved.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - deploy_demo_servers
  become: yes
```